# Changing values in column based on values in previous row in R

Tags: r, rename

I have a dataset that looks a bit like this:

```
Time Event           Value
1     right cue       4
2     right cue       5
3     reaction        6
4     reaction        7
5     reaction        5
6     left cue        7
7     left cue        4
8     reaction        2
```

I want to get the mean values between the start and end of the right and left reaction separately. My problem is the data is just labelled "reaction" without right or left. How would I rename "reaction" to "left/right reaction" based on the values (left or right cue) in the previous row?

Comment: Can you share expected output

Comment: Yes, I basically want my results to look like the above, except instead of just saying "reaction" at time 3, 4, 5 it should say "right reaction" (because it comes after the right cue). I would like "reaction" at time 8 to say "left reaction" (because it comes after the left cue). I know how to get the correct mean values once all the rows saying "reaction" refer to whether they are right or left reactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% mutate(dir = str_extract(Event, 'right|left')) %>% 
fill(dir, .direction = 'down') %>% 
mutate(Event = case_when(str_detect(Event, 'left|right') ~ Event, 
                         TRUE ~ str_c(dir,Event, sep = ' '))) %>% select(-dir)

# A tibble: 8 x 3
   Time Event          Value
  <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>
1     1 right cue          4
2     2 right cue          5
3     3 right reaction     6
4     4 right reaction     7
5     5 right reaction     5
6     6 left cue           7
7     7 left cue           4
8     8 left reaction      2
```

Comment: It doesn't. It is strange because I am not getting any error, the code appears to run, but my data remains unchanged. Nothing has been renamed.

Comment: Does your sample mimic your actual data? Because for data you shared in your question, we are getting the expected output.

Comment: Ah I found the issue. It was just a typo (upper instead of lower case in the string match), it is working now. Thank you.

Comment: @user5740534, if it worked, can you please accept the answer?